Evaluting $\int_0^\infty K_\nu(ax) K_\nu(bx) \sin(cx) dx$ missing from Erdelyi
There is a known integral, which converges for $\text{Re}(a+b)>0$, $c>0$ and $|\mathrm{Re}(\nu)| < \frac{1}{2}$ such that
$$
\int_0^\infty K_\nu(ax) K_\nu(bx) \cos(cx) dx = \frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{ab}} \sec(\nu \pi) P_{\nu - \frac{1}{2}} \left[ (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) (2ab)^{-1} \right]
$$
Given in Erdelyi's Table of Integral transforms, Volume I.
The related integral,
$$
\int_0^\infty K_\nu(ax) K_\nu(bx) \sin(cx) dx = ?
$$
is missing from Erdelyi. Can it be evaluated? I can't figure it out.
EDIT: $K_\nu$ is of course the modified Bessel function of the second kind. Also $P_{\nu - \frac{1}{2}}$ is a Legendre function.
EDIT: Some clarification on where the integral is missing from: The formula involving $\cos(cx)$ is given in formula 51 on page 50 of Erdely Volume I Table of Integral transforms (in the section 1.12 on cosine transforms involving Bessel functions). I would expect there to be an analogous formula in the section 2.12 on sine transforms involving Bessel functions (probably near formula 61 on page 107, as this is the most similar integral). Yet it is not there!

Are we to assume the same conditions on $a,b,c,\nu$ as for the cosine integral?

I suppose that would be the best. I have numerically evaluated the offending integral in Mathematica and it appears to converges to the same set of parameters as the first integral.

From where exactly is it missing?

@Nolord I updated the question with that info.

Let $I_{a,b,c} = \int_0^\infty K_\nu(ax) K_\nu(bx) \sin(cx) dx$. This answer will prove the following identity:
$$\boxed{I_{a,b,c} = \frac{c}{4ab} \pi \nu \csc(\pi \nu) \int_0^1 (1-x)^{-1/2} \,_{2}F_1 \left(1+\nu,1-\nu;\, 3/2;\, u(x)\right) dx}$$
where $u(x) = (-(a-b)^2-c^2x)(4ab)^{-1}$.
In particular, for $a=b$ we can apply Euler's integral transform for generalized hypergeometric functions to obtain the following closed form:
$$I_{a,a,c} = \frac{c}{2a^2} \pi \nu \csc(\pi\nu) \,_{3}F_2 (1+\nu,1-\nu,1;\,3/2,3/2; -c^2(4a^2)^{-1})$$
We also have $_{2}F_1(1+\nu,1-\nu;\, 3/2;\,-z) = \sinh(2\nu \operatorname{arcsinh}(\sqrt{z}))(z(1+z))^{-1/2}(2 \nu)^{-1}$ which allows to rewrite the integral using only elementary functions. I will also explain why the integral with $\sin(cx)$ is much harder than the one with $\cos(cx)$.
For $c \ll |a-b|$ we can also obtain:
$$I_{a,b,c} \approx \frac{c}{2ab} \pi \nu \csc(\pi\nu)\,_{2}F_1(1+\nu,1-\nu;\, 3/2;\, -(a-b)^2(4ab)^{-1})$$

Proof. Consider $\tilde{I}_{abc} = \int_0^\infty K_\nu(ax) K_\nu(bx) e^{icx} dx$. Using [1] and [2] we obtain
$$\tilde{I}_{abc} = \frac12 \int_0^\infty e^{icx} \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{t}{2} -\frac{a^2+b^2}{2t} x^2 \right) \frac{1}{t} \int_0^\infty \exp \left( -\frac{abx^2}{t} \cosh r\right) \cosh(\nu r) dr dt dx = $$
$$=\frac12 \int_0^\infty \cosh (\nu r) \int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{t} \exp \left( -\frac{t}{2} \right) \int_0^\infty \exp \left( -x^2 \left( \frac{a^2+b^2+2ab\cosh r}{2t}\right)\right) e^{icx} dx dt dr$$
Using [3]:
$$\tilde{I}_{abc} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{2}} \int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh (\nu r)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab \cosh r}} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \exp \left( -\frac{t}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2+2ab \cosh r}\right)\right) \left(1+i\operatorname{erfi} \left(\frac{c\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab \cosh r}}\right)\right) dt dr$$
Using [4] and [5]:
$$\tilde{I}_{abc} = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh (\nu r)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab \cosh r}} \left(1+\frac{2i}{\pi}\operatorname{arctanh} \left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab \cosh r}}\right)\right) dr$$
Here we can use [6] to have
$$\operatorname{Re} \tilde{I}_{a,b,c} = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh (\nu r) dr}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab \cosh r}} = $$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2ab}} \frac{\pi P_{\nu-1/2}((a^2+b^2+c^2)(2ab)^{-1})}{\sqrt{2}} \sec(\pi \nu) = $$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{ab}} \sec(\pi \nu) P_{\nu-1/2}((a^2+b^2+c^2)(2ab)^{-1})$$
which gives an expression for the integral with $\cos(cx)$. But for $\sin(cx)$ we have a harder integral:
$$I_{a,b,c} = \operatorname{Im} \tilde{I}_{a,b,c} = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh (\nu r) dr}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab \cosh r}} \operatorname{arctanh} \left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab \cosh r}}\right)$$
Here we are going to use Feynman’s technique to simplify this:
$$I_{a,b,c}(z) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh (\nu r) dr}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab \cosh r}} \operatorname{arctanh} \left(\frac{zc}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab \cosh r}}\right)$$
$$\frac{dI_{a,b,c}(z)}{dz} = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh (\nu r) dr}{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab \cosh r} \frac{c}{1 - \frac{z^2c^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab\cosh r}}$$
$$=\frac{c}{2ab}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh (\nu r)dr}{(a^2+b^2+c^2(1-z^2))(2ab)^{-1}+ \cosh r}$$
Using [6] we have
$$\frac{dI_{a,b,c}(z)}{dz} = \frac{c}{2ab} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\Gamma(1+\nu)\Gamma(1-\nu)}{(\omega(z)^2-1)^{1/4}} P_{\nu-1/2}^{-1/2}(\omega(z)),$$
where $\omega(z) = (a^2+b^2+c^2(1-z^2))(2ab)^{-1}$.
Since $I_{a,b,c}(0) = 0$ we can also write
$$I_{a,b,c} = \frac{c}{2ab} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \Gamma(1+\nu)\Gamma(1-\nu) \int_0^1 \frac{P_{\nu-1/2}^{-1/2}(\omega(z))}{(\omega(z)^2-1)^{1/4}} dz$$
Since $\Gamma(1+\nu)\Gamma(1-\nu) = \nu\Gamma(\nu)\Gamma(1-\nu) = \pi \nu \csc (\pi \nu)$:
$$I_{a,b,c} = \frac{c}{2ab} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \pi \nu \csc (\pi \nu) \int_0^1 \frac{P_{\nu-1/2}^{-1/2}(\omega(z))}{(\omega(z)^2-1)^{1/4}} dz$$
Using [7] we can rewrite:
$$I_{a,b,c} = \frac{c}{2ab} \pi \nu \csc (\pi \nu) \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1+\omega(z)}{2}\right)^{-1/2} \,_{2}F_1 \left(-\nu+1/2,\nu + 1/2;\, 3/2;\, {\frac {1-\omega(z)}{2}}\right) dz = $$
$$= \frac{c}{2ab} \pi \nu \csc (\pi \nu) \int_0^1 \,_{2}F_1 \left(1+\nu,1-\nu;\, 3/2;\,{\frac {1-\omega(z)}{2}}\right) dz$$
where in the last line we have used Euler's transformation.
Using substitution $x = 1-z^2$ we obtain
$$I_{a,b,c} = \frac{c}{4ab} \pi \nu \csc(\pi \nu) \int_0^1 (1-x)^{-1/2} \,_{2}F_1 \left(1+\nu,1-\nu;\, 3/2;\, u(x)\right) dx$$
where $u(x) = (-(a-b)^2-c^2x)(4ab)^{-1}$.

[1] $K_\nu (ax) K_\nu(bx) = \frac12 \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{t}{2} -\frac{a^2+b^2}{2t} x^2 \right) K_\nu \left( \frac{abx^2}{t}\right) \frac{dt}{t}$
[2] $K_\nu(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-z \cosh t} \cosh (\nu t) dt$
[3] $\int_0^\infty \exp(-px^2) e^{icx} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{p}} \exp\left(-\frac{c^2}{4p}\right) \left(1 + i\operatorname{erfi} \left( \frac{c}{2\sqrt{p}}\right)\right)$
[4] $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \exp(-pt) dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{p}}$
[5] $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \exp(-pt) \operatorname{erfi} (k\sqrt{t}) dt = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi p}} \operatorname{arctanh} \left( \frac{k}{\sqrt{p}}\right)$
[6] $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh (\nu r) dr}{(z + \cosh r)^{\mu+1/2}} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\Gamma(\nu+\mu+1/2)\Gamma(\mu-\nu+1/2)}{\Gamma(\mu+1/2)(z^2-1)^{\mu/2}} P^{-\mu}_{\nu-1/2}(z)$
[7] $P_{\nu}^{\mu}(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\mu)} \left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^{\mu/2}\,_{2}F_1 \left(-\nu ,\nu +1;1-\mu ;{\frac {1-z}{2}}\right)$

@Efim_Mazhnik Thank you for this great answer. You mention that you will explain why the integral with sin is so much harder than the one with cos, but I don't understand this point - why is this the case?

@QuantumEyedea basically due to exponential behavior of $K_\nu$ you have to have integrals of the type $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}$ cos(x) dx or $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \sin(x) dx$ at some point. The first one has a simple expression and does not complicate further steps, while the second one is more problematic (in the method above it brings an additional factor of $\operatorname{arctanh} (\cdots)$ to the integral)
